# how can I show array of array¿

Tags: javascript

I just want a way to return my tile map (array of an array)in the textarea, I mean at position
[0][1] for example it paints a # for 1 values and empty fill for 0 ones.

```
<script language="javascript">
var wall = "#";
var empty = "";
var mapa = [
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
];

function map() {
    for (i = 0; i < mapa.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < mapa[i].length; j++) {
            mapa[i][j];
        }
    }
}

function display(form) {
    var myform = form;
    myform.caja.value = map();
}
</script>
<body>
<form name=form>
<textarea name=caja cols=5 rows=5></textarea><br>
<input type=button value="click!" onclick="display(this.form)">
</form>
```

Comment: Your `map()` doesn't return anything.

Comment: therefore I said a way. I dont know how to do it

Comment: Well returning `undefined` certainly isn't a way. Have you made a real attempt at solving this?

Comment: I tried an If sentence mapa[i][j]==1 return wall but It didnt return nothing

Comment: Pass the textarea into the `map`, and when you have a `1`, have it assign `wall` to the `.value` using `+=`.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
function map(){
    var ret='';
    for(i=0;i<mapa.length;i++){
        for(j=0;j<mapa[i].length;j++){
            if(mapa[i][j]===0){
                ret +='#';
            }else{
                ret +=' ';
            }
        }
        ret +='\n';
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: I doubt you want a literal backslash. If you want a newline, then you want `"\n"`

Comment: thank you, but it worked more or less,instead of return a # rectangle with empty fill,the solution you explained draws a different shape than array is. Maybe "\r\n"?

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with

```
function print2dim(arr, charmap) {
    return arr.map(function(row) {
        return row.map(function(el) { return charmap[el]; }).join('');
    }).join("\n");
}

function display(form) {
    form.caja.value = print2dim(mapa, [" ", "#"]); // or {"0":" ","1":"#"}
}
```

([demo at jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/ABe37/))